# I want convert from Python to Scala that Partition Function using Vector

Tags: python, scala

I started studying Scala. It's difficult for me to understand Scala's collections.
I want to program the [Partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) function, but I'm referring to code already written using Python.
Could you tell me Scala's same code.

I use sbt 2.12.0.

I want to process big data.
I heard that the Vector type is fast, so I'm trying to use it, but can you tell me if there is a more appropriate collection type?
The Stream type was difficult to handle for me, but data could be stored using a lot of reverse.
Is the calculation slower if reverse processing is performed each time?

Python version

```py
class PartitionNumbers:
    def __init__(self):
        self.points_list = list()

    def _partition_function(self, n, k, tmp_list=[]):
        if n == 0:
            self.nums_list.append(tmp_list)
        elif n == 1:
            self.nums_list.append(tmp_list + [1])
        elif k == 1:
            self.nums_list.append(tmp_list + [1] * n)
        else:
            if n >= k:
                self._partition_function(n - k, k, tmp_list + [k])
            self._partition_function(n, k - 1, tmp_list)
        return self.points_list

    def create(self, n):
        self.points_list = list()
        return self._partition_function(n, n)
```

This code produces the following result:

```py
pn = PartitionNumbers()

pn.create(3)  # -> [[3], [2, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
pn.create(6)  # -> [[6], [5, 1], [4, 2], [4, 1, 1], [3, 3], [3, 2, 1], [3, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 1, 1], [2, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Scala version

```scala
object PartitionNumbers {

  def partitionFunction(n: Int, k: Int, v: Vector[Int] = Vector(), numsVector: Vector[Int] = Vector()): Vector[Int] = {
    var tmp: Vector[Int] = Vector()
    if (n == 0) {
      tmp ++= numsVector ++ v
    } else if (n == 1) {
      tmp ++= numsVector ++ v ++ List(1)
    } else if (k == 1) {
      tmp ++= numsVector ++ append(n, v)
    } else {
      if (n >= k) {
        partitionFunction(n - k, k, v :+ k, numsVector)
      }
      partitionFunction(n, k - 1, v, numsVector)
    }
    tmp
  }

  def append(n: Int, v: Vector[Int]): Vector[Int] = {
    if (n == 0) {
      v
    } else {
      append(n - 1, v :+ 1)
    }
  }

  def create(n: Int): Vector[Int] = {
    partitionFunction(n, n)
  }
}
```

I expect the output that same Python version, but the actual output is

```scala
Vector()
Vector()
```

(Add: 2019-09-27 17:49[JST])

I tried Stream type version. In my understanding that Stream type is able to add element at the head only, so the order of the numbers is reversed form the fist code.
The purpose of this code is to get the maximum value from the calculation result using the Partition Numbers.

```scala
import scala.math.floor

class PartitionNumbers(startNum: Int, point: Int) {
  var maxNum = 0
  var tmpNum = 0

  private def appendOnes(n: Int, s: Stream[Int] = Stream.empty[Int]): Stream[Int] = {
    if (n == 0) s
    else appendOnes(n - 1, 1 #:: s)
  }

  private def partition(n: Int, k: Int, tmpStream: Stream[Int] = Stream.empty): Int = {
    if (n == 0) tmpNum = addPercent(tmpStream)
    else if (n == 1 | k == 1) tmpNum = addPercent(appendOnes(n))
    else {
      if (n >= k) partition(n - k, k, k #:: tmpStream)
      partition(n, k - 1, tmpStream)
    }
    if (maxNum < tmpNum) maxNum = tmpNum
    maxNum
  }

  def searchMax(n: Int = point): Int = {
    partition(n, n)
  }

  def addPercent(usePointsStream: Stream[Int], num: Int = startNum): Int = {
    if (usePointsStream.isEmpty) {
      num
    } else {
      addPercent(usePointsStream.init, floor(num * (100 + usePointsStream.last) / 100).toInt)
    }
  }

}
```

It gave me next results:

```scala
val pn_1 = new PartitionNumbers(100, 10)
println(pn_1.searchMax())  // -> 110

val pn_2 = new PartitionNumbers(1000, 50)
println(pn_2.searchMax())  // -> 1630
```

The output of this code is correct, but `PartitionNumbers.point` can't process up to 100.
I need that is handling over 1,000.

What do I need right away: type understanding or other algorithm considerations?

(Add: 2019-09-28 03:11[JST])
add question: [Fixed Scala code using Partition Numbers with Stream calculate, BUT too slowly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58139520/fixed-scala-code-using-partition-numbers-with-stream-calculate-but-too-slowly)

Comment: You've already accepted an answer to this question. Updates to the question are unlikely to draw much attention.

Comment: Thanks, jwvh. When I think the discussion is over,  I check it what I think was most useful, doesn't I?

Comment: Yes, of course, but after an answer has been accepted don't add to the question. Question updates are likely to be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's lack of types is what makes it hard to transfer over.
It seems that even though `tmp_list`'s type would be `Vector[Vector[Int]]`, this:

```
(tmp_list + [2]) + [1] == [1, 2]
```

which is insane, it should be `[[1], [2]]` if it was strongly typed.

Given that, here is a direct translation:

```
class PartitionNumbers {
  private var pointsList: Vector[Vector[Int]] = null

  private def partition(n: Int, k: Int, tmpList: Vector[Int] = Vector.empty): Vector[Vector[Int]] = {
    if (n == 0) pointsList :+= tmpList
    else if (n == 1) pointsList :+= (tmpList :+ 1)
    else if (k == 1) pointsList :+= (tmpList ++ (1 to n).map(_ => 1).toVector)
    else {
      if (n >= k) partition(n - k, k, tmpList :+ k)
      partition(n, k - 1, tmpList)
    }

    pointsList
  }

  def create(n: Int): Vector[Vector[Int]] = {
    pointsList = Vector.empty
    partition(n, n)
  }
}
```

If you want to process big data however using "raw scala" (nothing like spark for example) a stream would be the way to go.  This is because it can read data a bit at a time and keep constant memory.  It will take a change of mindset into a more FP style to understand how to use them properly however.

I would recommend Akka streams or FS2 streams to do the job.

Here is a video from the Scala Toronto about FS2, its worth the watch:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B1wb4fIdtn4&t=2s

Comment: Thank you for useful advice. I'll try the Stream type, too. Actually, it becomes useless when it about `create(1000)`.