# Fixed Scala code using Partition Numbers with Stream calculate, BUT too slowly

Tags: algorithm, scala, recursion, max

**I want to talk about how to which proceed.**
1. Incorrect usage of Scala. I should try to more improve the code.
2. The efficiency of the algorithm is poor. I should think of an efficient algorithm.

**Goal**:
Can quickly calculate the max number from more than 1,000 Partition Numbers collections.

Partition Number:
e.g.,

> 5 -> (5), (1, 4), (2, 3), (1, 1, 3), (1, 2, 2), (1, 1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

I ask that ["I want to convert from Python to Scala that Partition Function using Vector"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58121565/i-want-convert-from-python-to-scala-that-partition-function-using-vector), and I was taught to use Stream yesterday.
I fixed code, I can use 10, 50, and so on. But using big numbers(e. g., 100, 1,000 or 10,000) weren't calculate max number.
It calculate from `Stream.last` to `Stream.head`.

In my understanding that Stream type can add an element at the head only, so the order of the numbers is reversed form the fist code.

**code**

```scala
import scala.math.floor

class PartitionNumbers(startNum: Int, point: Int) {
  var maxNum = 0
  var tmpNum = 0

  private def appendOnes(n: Int, s: Stream[Int] = Stream.empty[Int]): Stream[Int] = {
    if (n == 0) s
    else appendOnes(n - 1, 1 #:: s)
  }

  private def partition(n: Int, k: Int, tmpStream: Stream[Int] = Stream.empty): Int = {
    if (n == 0) tmpNum = calculate(tmpStream)
    else if (n == 1 | k == 1) tmpNum = calculate(appendOnes(n))
    else {
      if (n >= k) partition(n - k, k, k #:: tmpStream)
      partition(n, k - 1, tmpStream)
    }
    if (maxNum < tmpNum) maxNum = tmpNum
    maxNum
  }

  def searchMax(n: Int = point): Int = {
    partition(n, n)
  }

  def calculate(usePointsStream: Stream[Int], num: Int = startNum): Int = {
    if (usePointsStream.isEmpty) {
      num
    } else {
      calculate(usePointsStream.init, floor(num * (100 + usePointsStream.last) / 100).toInt)
    }
  }

}
```

**output example**

```scala
val pn_1 = new PartitionNumbers(100, 10)
println(pn_1.searchMax())  // -> 110

val pn_2 = new PartitionNumbers(1000, 50)
println(pn_2.searchMax())  // -> 1630

val pn_3 = new PartitionNumbers(10000, 100)
println(pn_3.searchMax())  // Can't calculate within 3 minutes using Ryzen 7 2700X.
```

Comment: your question is not very clear..

Comment: I need the performance that like `PartitionNumbers(100000000, 1000)` calculating is finished within 2 seconds.

Comment: All you need is the maximum value output by `calculate ()`, no intermediate array is needed.

Comment: My friend talked me that "you maybe more use `1`".

Comment: She said that if the underlying number exceeds the value that doesn't change when rounded down by multipling 1, perhaps it can be maximized by continuing to give 1 for the rest.